# Full tv out for iPhone 3GS or iPhone 4

Tags: iphone

Does the universal dock allow full tv out?  I have read on a few pages that it might.  But I don't know if it really does and if it supports more than just videos and Pictures.

If I use an iPhone 4 will it work?

Again I am looking for full video out. Not just videos and pictures.  I got the cord that says it is for tv out but it only supports videos, slideshows and selected apps (tv genie).   I am looking for more support than that.

Comment: I ended up jailbreaking and installing "TV Out". It allows for full mirroring on an iPhone 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I think you might be referring to mirroring, which is only supported by the iPad 2.

For other devices, it'll do video out as long as the app itself supports it, as you suggest.